# tag.php doesn't work with tags on a custom post type post?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, templates

here's another stumper.

I have a tag.php page. It works fine, unless you click a tag that is in a post associated with a custom post type. Then it doesn't work. Its like that tag, doesn't exist. But its just a tag that's used cross site.

I'm not too sure why? And the codex isn't helping much after a lot of searching.

anyone ever run into this issue? I'm stumped.

thanks.

Nadine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is related to your other question, what you've got is a custom *taxonomy*, so you need either a [`taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) (in your case `taxonomy-article_topics.php`), or just a more general `taxonomy.php` template.

(also, go back and accept answers to your other questions here if they've been solved!)

**UPDATE**

sorry, misunderstood your question-

add this to your `functions.php` template file to show your custom post types on tag pages:

```
function wpse28145_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if( is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // this gets all post types:
        $post_types = get_post_types();

        // alternately, you can add just specific post types using this line instead of the above:
        // $post_types = array( 'post', 'your_custom_type' );

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse28145_add_custom_types' );
```

Comment: I already have a taxonomy.php template, it serves as an archive for the article_topics. But the tags I'm using are site-wide already existing tags. 

So that's why I am confused...because this for example:  `<?php single_tag_title( ); ?> `  ...works fine, it just won't display any posts. 

(ok, re: accept answers...sorry).

Comment: @Nadine - see edit above.

Comment: Note that using this code results in no navigation on the tag page (WP 3.9.1).

Comment: Here is a refinement of this answer that accounts for the navigation. Search for 'Designophobia'. The person underneath them also suggests a less intrusive addition. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page?replies=3

Comment: @MiniRagnarok - just add a check for `$query->is_main_query()` to the above to exclude all queries except the main query.

Comment: @Milo I had already found another solution that worked (the one that I linked to). I decided to test out your new solution and it works too. Everything looks great. Thanks! :)

Comment: i wonder, why this is not working for me. i am MORE THAN sure, that i wrote everything correct, but my custom post type "project" wont show up. i now wrote `$post_types = array( 'any' );` and it works fine, but putting `get_post_types()` or `array('post', 'project')` does not work. wordpress says: empty. s-t-r-a-n-g-e