# Tags and Taxonomy links not working for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags, urls

In my theme, I registered a taxonomy by the name of `tax_groups` for a custom post type named `custom_items`.
So the following URL was returning the lastest `custom_items`
    http://website.com/custom_items/

The Search widget was also working perfectly fine but not Tag and Taxonomy links like these:

```
http://website.com/tag/a_random_tag/
http://website.com/tax_groups/a_random_group/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify queries before they run. So the best practice was to add the following code to function.php:

```
if (!function_exists('my_theme_filter')) {
    function my_theme_filter( $query ){

    if ( $query->is_main_query() )
        if ( $query->get( 'tag' ) OR is_search() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'artprim_item' ) );

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($query); echo '</pre>';

    return $query;
}}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_theme_filter' );
```

- `if ( is_search() )` was necessary for taxonomy, this is what made this URL works :

  http://website.com/tax_groups/a_random_group/

  It's surprising and made me lost a lot of time since the search by itself was already working just fine
- `if ( $query->get( 'tag' ) )` obviously was necessary for

  http://website.com/tag/a_random_tag/

Comment: I wanted to mention that the method described in [this question] (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/tag-php-doesnt-work-with-tags-on-a-custom-post-type-post) solved the problem for me.