# Tag.php not displaying posts with the tag

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

Ive got a CPT and in my CPT's argument I am calling the taxonomy `post_tag`.  When I create a `tag.php` file it doesn't show any of the posts for said tag.  My `tag.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <p>Tag: <?php single_tag_title(); ?></p>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php endwhile;     
            else: ?>
                <p>not working</p>          
            <?php endif; ?>             
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In my research I ran across "[tag.php doesn't work with tags on a custom post type post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/tag-php-doesnt-work-with-tags-on-a-custom-post-type-post)" but I am using what I thought was the default for tags `post_tag`.  When I was referencing `WP_Query()` Tag Parameters it doesn't show how to take into consideration for the tag clicked. When I search for tag.php I get [Tag Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) and it doesn't show any examples that take into consideration all tags.  What is the proper way to write a `WP_Query()` for all posts pertaining to the tag?  I did run across [`wp_get_post_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) after some research and reading "[Wordpress get related pages (tag based) - wp_get_post_tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911300/wordpress-get-related-pages-tag-based-wp-get-post-tags)" but I'm not understanding the rewrite for tag.php and the codex has no examples.  So how can I properly write my tag.php to return all posts for the clicked tag?

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to add your cpt to the main query on tag pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [Pieter's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203239/tag-php-not-displaying-posts-with-the-tag#comment295054_203239):

In `functions.php` I added:

```
function tag_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_tag) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'custom_post_type', ));
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','tag_filter');
```

Comment: This kills the tag.php query in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me. I also wanted to include other post types, so I added:

```
$query->set('post_type', array( 'custom_post_type', 'post', 'page' ));
```